# Is there any way to make this if statement shorter and cleaner?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement, operators

I have this long if statement to see if a string is equal to any number up to 9. But it is so long and takes a lot of space. Is there any way to make it shorter and cleaner? I'm new to programming.

```
if calculated == "1" or calculated == "2" or calculated == "3" or calculated == "4" or calculated == "5" or calculated == "6" or calculated == "7" or calculated == "8" or calculated == "9":
```

Comment: if calculated in ['1','2','3',...]:

Comment: `if calculated in {'1', '2', ...}:`.

Comment: at least for once this duplicate isn't used for questions like `if a == 12 or 13 or 15` ...

Comment: @Kasrâmvd not sure it's an exact duplicate, as OP seems to imply that the numbers as string follow. I'm contemplating reopening, but what do you think?

Comment: its testing one variabl against multiple values :) sounds different

Comment: `len(calculated)==1 and calculated!='0' and calculated.isdigit()` :=

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think it's close enough to be a duplicate of that one but if you think it's not feel free to add a proper one because I'm sure there are endless number of questions like this already. (I just added one!)

Comment: yes, the new added question is _very_ close. The point is: it's difficult to find exact duplicates if you don't know them already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
if calculated in ['1','2','3',...,'9']:
    # do
```

or you can do this:

```
if calculated in [str(i) for i in range(1, 10)]:
    # do
```

also this way is possible too:

```
if calculated in list(map(str, range(1, 10))):
   # do
```

Comment: Yeah ok! Thanks the first one seems the easiest, but i will keep the others in mind! Thanks again!

Comment: @Erik77 your welcome. if you find my answer helpful please check the green one beside the question.

Comment: In Python 3.x it should be simple a `if calculated in  '1,2,3,4':` , 3.2 and newer will recognise this as an immutable constant. This is the fastest option for newer code.

Comment: you don't need to force iteration, even in python 3. Just use `calculated in map(str, range(1, 10))`

Comment: @pygo its an O(n) test - predefining a set of 1char strings and testing that is O(1) so faster

Comment: your last 2 method profit from doing the conversion _outside_ the testing code itself - consider using this in a tight loop - you would recreate and recreate and recreate and reacreate (you get it) the list you look into. Also: list membership testing is O(n) (if you find it in the last possible place) whereas `set` - testing is O(1) constant. Especially if you reuse the test, use `set`.

Comment: This is the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations) for immutable  constants..

Comment: @pygo - I dacor with `{"1","2","3",...,"9"}` - but you are just providing a string - wich is essentially an iterable. the optimisation is about recognizing a `{....}` as frozenset instead normal set if used in a condition - not about splitting your string at `,` and creating a `frozenset` from it. Or is it? Thanks for the link, gotta remember that one - I would have thought pre-creating the set is faster then inlining it.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, well said.

Answer (score 3):

This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). If you know your string is a number, you should cast it to a number and use integer based logic:

```
if 1 <= int(calculated) <= 9:
    pass
```

But if that doesn’t work for some reason, your logic could be simplified to checking a range:

```
if calculated in (str(n) for n in range(1, 10)):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, say, in this simple case,

```
try:
    if int(calculated) in range(1, 10):
```

Or vice versa:

```
if calculated in map(str, range(1, 10)):
```

Comment: thumbs up for the int conversion which allows O(1) testing in `range`. In that case, go further and use `if 1 <= int(calculated) < 10` which is even faster because it doesn't create a range object :)

Comment: Sure, I've thought about posting simple comparison but considered it not generic enough. :)